# error C2784 c++ std::map with 2 user-defined types

Tags: c++

could someone please explain why this code produces. i was able to narrow the error to this segment regardless of what I set the map value to.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\xstddef(117,1): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(std::nullptr_t,const std::shared_ptr<_Ty> &) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::shared_ptr<_Ty> &' from 'const _Ty'

```
struct Vector2i
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
std::map<Vector2i, Chunk*> map{};
map.insert({ Vector2i{0,0}, nullptr });
```

thanks :)

I tried commenting out all other instances of the Vector2i struct and this segment seemed to be the only place that causes this error.

Comment: std::map orders it's items using a comparison function. If you don't specify the default is `std::less<key>` where key is your `Vector2i`

Comment: For comparison, gcc says `error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Vector2i' and 'const Vector2i')` and clang says `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const Vector2i' and 'const Vector2i')` (pointing to an expression like `__x < __y`). Weird that MSVC complains about template deduction for `shared_ptr` in this situation.

Comment: I could not reproduce the shared_ptr part but I did get a few C2784 errors: [https://godbolt.org/z/4qebT7ovE](https://godbolt.org/z/4qebT7ovE) msvc was not as helpful with this error as g++

Answer (score 3):

The [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is an ordered container, and therefore requires keys to provide a "less-than" operator for comparison. This can be provided in the map's template arguments, or it can be implicit if you have defined `operator<` for your type.

```
struct Vector2i
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator<(const Vector2i& other) const {
        return x < other.x || x == other.x && y < other.y;
    }
};
```

Comment: Or just `std::tie(x, y)  < std::tie(other.x, other.y)`

Answer (score 2):

You should provide comparison operator to your map. Here is some ways.

Define operator< inside struct.

```
struct Vector2i
{
    ...   
    bool operator<(const Vector2i& rhs) const {
        return x < rhs.x;
    }
};
```

Define outside the struct.

```
bool operator< (const Vector2i& lhs, const Vector2i& rhs) {
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```

Define struct comparator and pass to constructor of map.

```
struct cmpByStringLength {
    bool operator()(const Vector2i& lhs, const Vector2i& rhs) const {
       return lhs.x < rhs.x;  
    }
};

std::map<Vector2i, Chunk*, cmpByStringLength> mp{};
```

Using lambda function.

```
auto comp = [](const Vector2i& a, const Vector2i& b) { return a.x < b.x; };
std::map<Vector2i, Chunk*, decltype(comp)> mp{};
```